# how can i solve this problem of dart null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

[this the screenshot of the error that i found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fkVH.png)

Comment: that error has nothing to do with null safety

Comment: so what should i do

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't see what type `data` is, so it considers it as type `Object`. `Object` doesn't have a `[]` operator. Assuming that data is actually a `Map` you can try to replace

```
var data = doc.data();
```

with

```
Map? data = doc.data() as Map?;
```

Although there might be a nicer way to write this, but that's hard to know without seeing more of your code. Usually you can indicate the type already somewhere above it by using `<Map>` at the right place